# Creating a new user with credentials, then obtaining a token for that user with Doorkeeper in an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm building an API, protected by Doorkeeper.

If I manually create the user (with password) in the backend, and then post the following to `oauth/token`, Doorkeeper successfully generates an access token for the user and returns it:

```
data = {
    username: $("#email_sign_in").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: '880c16e50aee5893446541a8a0b3788....',
    client_secret: 'a5108e1a1aeb87d0bb49d33d8c50d....',
    provider: 'identity'
}
```

However, I'm trying to get my head around how I could do a sign up flow.

I've happily got `users/create` working, in so far as it creates a user and password, but I'm not sure how to then generate the Doorkeeper::AccessToken in the next step, and return it to the client.  Ideally, after creating the user in the user#create action I'd then redirect to POST to `oauth/token`, with the user's name and password, but I know that you can't redirect to a POST.

I've had a dig around the Doorkeeper source, but am getting a bit lost in all this clever middleware.  Any advice on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It was the simplest of things!  I was overcomplicating it by trying to POST, when in actual fact I could simply generate the DoorKeeper::AccessToken in user#create, and then return this.

Here's the code to generate the token:

```
access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(:application_id => application_id, :resource_owner_id => user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! But `render status: 201, json: Doorkeeper::OAuth::TokenResponse.new(access_token)` doesn't provide the json access_token! Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @SagarRanglani try `render json: Doorkeeper::OAuth::TokenResponse.new(access_token).body.to_json`

Comment: @leomayleomay the `to_json` is redundant and not necessary

Answer (score 6):

I dig a bit in the doorkeeper source code, like the way that creating token using standard api way, you'd better using the following method if you are manually doing this.

```
find_or_create_for(application, resource_owner_id, scopes, expires_in, use_refresh_token)
```

for your case

```
access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for(application: application, resource_owner_id: user_id)
```

link to source code of doorkeeper
[find_or_create_for in doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/4313541e4d806cd8e5cad20d4ca4444171c113d2/lib/doorkeeper/models/access_token_mixin.rb#L70)

Comment: for a new user does not make sense to use `find_or`. Is it assumed a new user does not have any access token yet.

Answer (score 3):

In rails we can create access token using DoorKeeper using:

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(
  application_id: nil,
  resource_owner_id: user.id,
  expires_in: 2.hours,
  scopes: 'public'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the best answer is not the one you posted, I think itś better to create a controller that inherits from `Doorkeeper::TokensController`:

```rb
# app/controllers/custom_tokens_controller.rb
class CustomTokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  # Override create action
  def create
    (... your custom code ...)
    super
  end
end
```

Then in `routes.rb` define a new route like `post 'custom_tokens', to: 'custom_tokens#create'` or whatever naming you prefer, but the action should be `create`.

More details about this solution here: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow